# Catch error in RxJS and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, rxjs

I have been using package `rx` in NodeJS and everything is ok. Now, I tried to use `rxjs` (newer version of `rx`), and I don't understand anything.

When my Observable fails, I want to transform it in another one. Tipically, I would do it with `catch`, but it doesn't work anymore.

```
//I know it will never fail but it's just for the example
Rx.of(4).catch(err => Rx.of(7));
```

But I get:

> Rx.of(...).catch is not a function

Same with `onErrorResumeNext`

```
Rx.of(4).onErrorResumeNext(Rx.of(7));
```

> Rx.of(...).onErrorResumeNext is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`catch` is renamed with `catchError` from `RxJs 6.0`.

They introduced a new operator called `pipe` where you can add infinite number of chained operation including error catching.

```
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

Rx.of(4)
  .pipe(
    catchError(err => Rx.of(7))
   )
```

Reference : https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html

Comment: Thank you very much. Understood. I had to use `const { catchError } = require('rxjs/operators');` instead, because I'm using Node. I will accept in 6 minutes :P